# Problems Connecting to Remote PSQL on Linux Server

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, psql, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a linux server with PSQL installed (psql (15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg22.04+1))). This is installed on Oracle Cloud.

I am trying to connect using the command

```
psql -h 129.213.17.88 -p 5432 -d breedingdb -U postgres
```

Where 129.213.17.88 is the public IP of the server in Oracle.

Error message:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "129.213.17.88", port 5432 failed: No route to host
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

[sudo systemctl status postgresql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZtcO.png)

I have changed postgresql.conf to include:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

I have changed pg_hba.conf to include:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                  md5
```

After that `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

[inbound rules on Oracle cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCgc9.png)

```
netstat -an | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have no problems connecting
[locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyNhW.png)

sudo nmap -sS 129.213.17.88 -p 5432

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-02-22 18:19 UTC
Nmap scan report for 129.213.17.88
Host is up (0.00042s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

ping 129.213.17.88

```
PING 129.213.17.88 (129.213.17.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 129.213.17.88: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.508 ms
64 bytes from 129.213.17.88: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.498 ms
64 bytes from 129.213.17.88: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.483 ms
^C
--- 129.213.17.88 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2043ms
```

Comment: Feels like a networking issue. Does `nc 129.213.17.88  5432` ran from your client-side get a connection or does it hang?

Comment: @JNevill using '-v' it says: connect to 129.213.17.88 port 5432 (tcp) failed: No route to host

Comment: @JNevill using '-v' it says: connect to 129.213.17.88 port 5432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCI support team has jump into a call with me and they were able to provide me with the solution.

As shown in the question, network level changes to allow connection to port 5432 were made previously in OCI (inbound rules).

I was missing changes at the firewall level:

Edit `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Add the following line where 5432 is PSQL port:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

Save and Exit

Then, we need to restart iptables `netfilter-persistent restart`
To see if rules were applied:

```
iptables -L
```

It should have there:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:postgresql
```

I have to mention this is unsecure. Do it at your own risk. It works for my purposes.

Then use the command `psql -h ip_address -d dbname -U username -W` to connect to a password protected remote database.

I tried connecting using the private and the public ip and they both work. Both intances were on the same VCN.

Successfully connected to breedingdb:
[image: breedingdb]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check/add iptables rules for that port?

https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/enabling-network-traffic-to-ubuntu-images-in-oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Does `sudo nmap -sS <private ip> -p 5432` show the port as open?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it. In the process of solving it I was able to track specific errors, what caused them, and the solutions to those errors. First I installed telnet to help me debug connections to the server. I ran the following command:-

```
telnet <server IP eg.88.222.333.11> 5432
```

One of the errors that I encounter was

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

This error occurs when you have not configured your `iptables` to accept traffic from the device that you are working on. This can be solved by adding an entry to the IP Table

```
# update iptables and allow traffic from target IP eg. 105.222.22.222
sudo nano /etc/iptables/rules.v4
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 105.222.22.222/32 --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# effect change to the iptables
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
sudo iptables -L
```

The other error that I encountered is

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

This error occurs when you have not configured your `postgresql.conf` to listen for traffic from the device that you are working on. This can be solved by finding the `listen_addresses` entry and set to a specific IP or using a wildcard to listen for traffic from any device.

open the `postgresql.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf
```

and modify the `listen_addresses` entry

```
...
listen_addresses = '*'
...
```

The last error that I encountered was when I tried to connect to the db:

```
psql -h 88.222.333.11 -p 5432 -U username db_name -W
> password
```

was

```
psql: error: connection to server at "88.222.333.11", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "105.222.22.222", user "blabla", database "foobar", SSL encryption
connection to server at "88.222.333.11", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "105.222.22.222", user "blabla", database "foobar", no encryption
```

This error occurs when you have not configured your `pg_hba.conf` to accept traffic from the device that you are working on. This can be solved by adding an entry to the `pg_hba.conf` file.
Open the file

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf
```

and add an entry for your device at the end of the file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             105.222.22.222/32       md5
```

then remember to restart your postgres `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`.

Something else to look out for is when adding an IP remember to append the `/32` for it to match a specific IP for good security. Also, remember to add an ingress rule in your network security configuration to allow traffic from your device

Answer (score -1):

sudo ufw allow 5432

try this command, it solves my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).